# Java web start: shared library on client machine

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-3d

I have to use a simulator which its author has published it as java web start application. The simulator uses java3d for visualization, however, the application can be executed without java3d (with limited features of course). We have java3d installed in our machines but the location of jar files and `libj3dcore-ogl.so` is different from the default locations. And the problem is, I am not able to make the application work with java3d.

I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but there was no success. My question has two folds. Firstly, how can I tell `javaws` where to look for `.so` file (or java3d jar files if it matters)? Is there anything to do by modifying the `jnpl` file or, passing some argument through `-J` option in command line?

Secondly, I am no expert in java web start. With said, is it not the case that all dependencies are downloaded from the publisher's servers and are cached on client machine? If so, why should be any problem with java3d in the first place?

Please note that I am on the client side and I do not have possibility to modify the source code. Furthermore, we do not have root access in our machines and everything is done in our home directory.

Comment: Normally the author should have included Java3D in his webstart application. Can you copy and paste the content of his jnlp file so we can see if Java3D exists there?

Comment: @SaeidNourian, I have to ask them if it is fine to share their `jnlp` since this is designed for internal use only. Apart from that, I had a look at the resources in the `jnlp` and it seems all java3d jars are included. I do not know however, if they have also encapsulated the `.so` file in a jar file or not.

Comment: See if you see a line like this in your jnlp: <nativelib href="../common/jogl/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar"/>. Also see if you can run my Java3D webstart program: http://www.runiter.com/webstart/gc3/grapher.jnlp

Comment: @SaeidNourian, thank you for concern. I tried your application and it seems to be launched without problem. However, there is no 2d or 3d rendering of the plots and application get blocked in matter of few seconds. Check [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/dgS2lLa.png) screenshot to see what I mean. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, looks like a problem with video card driver. Can you send me the error log? To do that click on Help > Send Error Log...